# Which would be the best implementation strategy for a dynamic system with stick-slip friction

Tags: math, physics, numeric, microsoft-dynamics

[image: Kinetics and kinematics]

I'm trying to build a theoretical model of a lead screw drive to involve in mbs-simulations as a force element. Which means

```
F=blackbox(u)
```

I simplified the system into a represantative model in the picture above. The phi_1(t) and u_1(t) is the given motion of the nut. The motion of the lead and the returned reaction forces should be calculated. Those are the phi_2(t) and u_2(t).

I wrote all of the equations for a static case. But I am not sure how I should approach to choose the motions of equations to solve them numerically.

You see in the kinematics that there is one internal degree of freedom. You can choose it as u_2. So there is one possible position of phi_2 by given phi_1 and u_1.

Now you can write the axial force F and torque M depending on u_2. So you can calculate tangential and normal forces which affect on screw thread.

At this point I get difficulties. The friction force F_R may take two different values depending on thread forces because of stick slip effect.

How would you go ahead to write the equations of motion, so that you can implement it to solve numerically?

I would also be glad for mentioning any other communities/literature which could help to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Friction is a non-linear effect, so you'll have to solve the equations of motion in a non-linear way: Start with an initial condition, increment the system, iterate to convergence, update the state, repeat for the next step.

Friction is a difficult topic in non-linear mechanics.  Non-linear finite element vendors like MARC, MSC, Ansys, and Abacus were solving these problems in a general way back in the 90s when I did finite element analysis for a living.  I'd look into something like that.

A Google search for "open source non-linear finite element analysis" returned [this](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&gcx=w&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=bing&safe=active#fp=b33438c1dff08b52&q=open%20source%20nonlinear%20finite%20element&safe=active).